# winrt unselect ListView Item when click outside

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime

How can I unselect all ListView items when I click outside the ListView in xaml for Windows Store Application?
When I add handlers to LostFocus event I unselect all but in case when I just want to chenge selected item LostFocus event also triggers. 
Can anyone share the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about waiting a bit after LostFocus to see if it was indeed lost. Like by calling RunAsync on Dispatcher? Seems a bit like a hack, but it could work.